# BindingResult for validation errors, what about business errors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I understand that the BindingResult is meant for validation errors relating to the form. However, what about business errors, for example:

```
public String bulkUpdate(@ModelAttribute form, BindingResult r) {
//do validation, extract selected issues to be bulk updated, etc.
//any form related, binding errors to be put in r

//this part
List<String> results = service.bulkUpdate(issues, newValues);

//where is it appropriate to put the results?
//from experience we just create a request attribute and put it there
request.setAttribute("bulkUpdateErrors", StringUtils.join(results, "<br>"))

//is there an similar generic structure like Errors?
}
```

And in the jsp:

```
<div id='info'> 
    <c:if test="${not empty bulkUpdateErrors}">
        <spring:message code="bulk.update.warning" /> ${bulkUpdateErrors}
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Is there a similar generic structure to put business errors?

Comment: thanks Jelies for formatting jsp/html snippet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101148/how-to-add-error-on-spring-mvc-simpleformcontroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use separated object as you suggest or you can add business errors to `Errors/BindingResult`. Personally, I usually put bussiness errors inside BindingResult because later is easier to show them in JSP/View. I don't know if there is any generic structure for this purpose.

Using `r.rejectValue("property", "error.object");`, it's enough for that. Or if you want, global error can be registered calling `r.reject("error.object");`